# JavaScript: filter array of objects using string matching of ANY value

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I want to create a function that when given a string will search each object in an array for any matching value of that string. I have a function below but was wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

For example if we have the array:

```
data = [
  {name: "Jordan", age: "forty two"},
  {name: "Maya", age: "thirty"}
]
```

Using my function (that I'm hoping has a neater alternative)

```
searchAllObject = (data, letter) => {
  let subsetData = []
  let indexedObjects = []
  let singleObject = []
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j <  Object.values(data[i]).length; j++) {
      singleObject.push(Object.values(data[i])[j].toLowerCase().includes(letter.toLowerCase()))
    }
    indexedObjects = singleObject.reduce((a, b) => a || b, false)
    indexedObjects ? subsetData.push(data[i]) : null
    singleObject = []
  }
  return subsetData
}
```

## Desired Output

I can use my function to search for `m` and it will return only `data[1]` while `j` will return only data[0] and `y` will return both elements:

```
searchAllObject(data, 'j')
```

```
[{name: "Jordan", age: "forty two"}]
```

---

```
searchAllObject(data, 'm')
```

```
[{name: "Maya", age: "thirty"}]
```

---

```
searchAllObject(data, 'y')
```

```
[
  {name: "Jordan", age: "forty two"},
  {name: "Maya", age: "thirty"}
]
```

**note - my function DOES work but I was wondering if the internet could help me find something nicer than a nested for loop!**

Comment: `data.filter(d => Object.values(d).some(v => v.toLowerCase().includes("j")))`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a more elegant solution using [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

In the end you wanna have a subset of the list so therefore `filter()` is your primary operation. Then you need to determine for each item in the array whether it should be included in the result or not. It should be included if any of (or `some()` meaning at least one) of the values of this object (here is where `Object.values()` comes into play) contains (or `includes()`) the search term.

```js
const data = [
  { name: "Jordan", age: "forty two" },
  { name: "Maya", age: "thirty" },
];

function searchAllObjectsCaseInsensitive(data, searchTerm) {
  const lowerCaseSearchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
  return data.filter((obj) =>
    Object.values(obj).some((val) =>
      val.toLowerCase().includes(lowerCaseSearchTerm)
    )
  );
}

console.log(searchAllObjectsCaseInsensitive(data, 'j'))
console.log(searchAllObjectsCaseInsensitive(data, 'm'))
console.log(searchAllObjectsCaseInsensitive(data, 'y'))
```

```css
/* Stackoverflow: show only console */
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably express your intent a little bit better if you decouple matching from filtering.

Let's start with matching:

```js
const matches =
  (str, obj) =>
    ( Object.values(obj)
    . join('')
    . toLowerCase()
    . includes(str.toLowerCase()));

matches('j', {name: 'Jordan', age: 'forty two'});
//=> true
```

Then filter:

```js
data.filter(obj => matches('m', obj));
//=> [{name: 'Maya', age: 'thirty'}]
```

Can we improve?

Considering this question was tagged with [functional-programming](/questions/tagged/functional-programming) I feel obliged to include some currying ;)

```js
const matches =
  str => obj =>
    ( Object.values(obj)
    . join('')
    . toLowerCase()
    . includes(str.toLowerCase()));

data.filter(matches('m'));
//=> [{name: 'Maya', age: 'thirty'}]
```

Can we improve even more?

Maybe but YMMV ;) I include it for the sake of completeness but personally I wouldn't do this.

```js
// recursive curried function for fun
const matches =
  str => obj =>
    typeof obj == 'string'
      ? obj.toLowerCase().includes(str.toLowerCase())
      : Object.values(obj).some(matches(str));


data.filter(matches('m'));
//=> [{name: 'Maya', age: 'thirty'}]
```

Hope this helps